# VB.NET Entity Framework access multiple database server with several DbContext classes

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture

I have a test database and a live database located on different servers. My current design manages to work with both but I'd like to improve the access. I am out of ideas by now and want your opinion.

---

**Question**:

How can I solve the following design problem?

I created two EF6 classes to access the different databases. (Highlighted ones)
[image: EF6-classes]

On program start I define a default connection depending on the build mode.

```
#If DEBUG Then
        myDbType = AbstractDBAccess.DatabaseType.Test
#Else
        myDbType = AbstractDBAccess.DatabaseType.Live
#End If
```

I then use myDBType to create DBAccess objects to interact with my DB. From now on it automatically takes care to connect to either test or live DB.

```
Dim userAccess = new UserDBAccess(myDBtype)
userAccess.GetUser()
userAccess.Dispose()

Dim projectAccess = new ProjectDBAccess(myDBType)
projectAccess.DoWork()
projectAccess.Dispose()
```

I got this idea after watching a SW-Architecture video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA-Hp4aBWb4 which I modified to my needs.

So until now this looks like a very clean way but I run into trouble.

My problem is that for each database access I have to copy/paste 99% of my code depending on which server I want to access. E.G.

For the live DB: ctxLive < @see code below

For the testDB: ctxTest < @see code below

I have a base class from which all DBAccess classes derive.

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Public MustInherit Class AbstractDBAccess
    Implements IDisposable
#Region "Fields"
    ' Access live db via EF 6
    Protected ctxLive As DBLiveEntities

    ' Access test db via EF 6
    Protected ctxTest As DBTestEntities

    ' Remember DB to access
    Protected myDBType As DatabaseType
#End Region
#Region "Enum"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Add more data bases here.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Matthias Köhler</remarks>
    Public Enum DatabaseType
        Live = 0
        Test = 1
    End Enum
#End Region
#Region "Constructor"
    Public Sub New(ByVal dbType As AbstractDBAccess.DatabaseType)

        myDBType = dbType ' 

        ' Depending on what type we get from startup we grant access to test or live DB
        Select Case dbType
            Case DatabaseType.Live
                Me.ctxLive = New DBLiveEntities

            Case DatabaseType.Test
                Me.ctxTest = New DBTestEntities
        End Select
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
    Public Function GetDBAccess() As DbContext
        ' My Problem is i need to return two different types in this method.
        ' After creating an instance I save which access this object was intended for with "myDBType"
        ' Both classes derive from DbContext but if I implement it this way I can't see my tables. See screenshot below.
        Select Case myDBType
            Case DatabaseType.Live
                Return Me.ctxLive
            Case DatabaseType.Test
                Return Me.ctxTest
        End Select

        Throw New Exception("No matching case for " & myDBType.ToString)
    End Function
#End Region
```

---

**The Problem**:

You see the Select-Case is 99% the same. Imagine this for complicated code and 15 classes. I just don't like that copy pasting. I just need to change the "ctxLive" or "ctxTest".

Imagine that someone has to add another DB in some years. He has to go through the whole code and add a case to each method.

**Isn't there a better way?**

[image: Can't-see-tables]

Here the matching code for this screenshot.

```
Public Class UserDBAccess
    Inherits AbstractDBAccess
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Sub New(ByVal dbType As AbstractDBAccess.DatabaseType)
        MyBase.New(dbType)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetUser()
        ' Currently I have to add a lot of select cases to seperate my live DB and test DB.
        ' They have different connection strings and are on different servers
        Select Case Me.myDBType
            Case DatabaseType.Live
                Me.ctxLive.CCTUsers.Where(Function(u) u.UserName.Contains("StackOverflow"))
            Case DatabaseType.Test
                Me.ctxTest.CCTUsers.Where(Function(u) u.UserName.Contains("StackOverflow"))
        End Select

        ' I have a lot of Copy Pasting which in my opinion is ugly.
        ' I want sth like this to save me all that select cases
        ' The difference here is the "GetDBAccess" 
        Me.GetDBAccess.CCTUsers.Where(Function(u) u.UserName.Contains("StackOverflow"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Typically this is handled through configuration.  The context loads from whatever database connection is set in the configuration. The configuration used is tied to the build mode. Then there is only the need for one database context.

Comment: I'm on it. You gave me a good idea. I will answer in case I solved this issue.

Comment: I would suggest use custom groups in the app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is definitely cleaner and easier to maintain in future.

Add connection strings to your app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_Live" connectionString="liveDB" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DB_Test" connectionString="testDB" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Create a DBEntityManager

```
Public Class DBEntityManager
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New(ByVal connString As String)
    MyBase.New(connString)
End Sub

Public Overridable Property MyTable() As DbSet(Of MyTable)

End Class
```

Then I added a reference to the ConfigurationManager:

1. Right click your project (Not the solution)
2. Add -> Reference ... -> Framework
3. Search for "Configuration" and activate the check box for "System.Configuration"
4. Click "OK"

On start up I configure the connection string depending on the build mode

```
#If DEBUG Then
        connString = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB_Test").ConnectionString()
#Else
        connString = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB_Live").ConnectionString()
#End If
```

I re-factored my base class to look like this.

It now takes the connection string and creates a DBEntityManager object.
DBEntityManager derives from DBContext and works with the connection string passed.

```
Public Class DBAccessAbstract
    Implements IDisposable

#Region "Field Declaration"
    Protected ctx As DBEntityManager
#End Region

#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New(ByVal connString As String)
        ctx = New DBEntityManager(connString)
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                Me.ctx.Dispose()
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

For each table I create accessors as I wanted to

```
Public Class DBAccessUserTable
Inherits DBAccessAbstract
Implements IDisposeable

Public Sub New(ByVal connString as String)
MyBase.New(connString)
End Sub
  Public Function Exists(ByVal userName As String) As Boolean
    Dim user As UserTable

        user = Me.ctx.UserTables.Where(Function(e) e.UserName.Contains("StackOverflow")).FirstOrDefault
        If IsNothing(user) Then Return False
        Return True
  End Function
End Class
```

Now I can access either test or live DB automatically by creating a new instance of my DBAccess class

```
Dim dbEmpl As New DBAccessUserTable(Me.connString)
            If Not dbEmpl.Exists(userName) Then Throw New System.Exception(userName & " doesn't exist.")
            MessageBox.Show("True!")
            dbEmpl.Dispose()
```

Thanks for giving me the idea!

Comment: You can take it one step further and simply have a single connection string in the config file, which can be populated with the proper value based on the chosen build configuration.

Comment: I will keep that in mind thanks. But I need to implement a new feature and don't have the time to dig any deeper. It works fine by now and I am happy. Took me ~ 2:30 h to fix stupid copy/paste errors. When I have more time I will try and update this depending on your advise. Thanks!